# Why all the fields are correctly stored except one?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a Provider like this:

```
$provider = Provider::create([
    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'is_available' => 1,
    'is_activated' => 1,
    'insurance' => 1
]);

Log::info($provider);
```

The Provider is actually well created, and all fields are stored correctly except the insurance field.

The insurance field isn't working and I can't figure out why.

It was created with Laravel migration tools, like this:

```
class AddInsuranceToProvidersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('providers', function($table) {
            $table->integer('insurance');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And then from terminal:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan cache:clear
```

And here is how it looks like from phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Any idea why I can't save any value to insurance field?

Also when I log the $provider variable, there is nothing related with insurance field, as you can see there:

> [2017-12-13 12:36:54] local.INFO:
>   {"first_name":"fef","last_name":"ewfe","email":"fel.bruno2njtz3@gmail.com","is_available":1,"is_activated":1,"updated_at":"2017-12-13
>   12:36:54","created_at":"2017-12-13 12:36:54","id":276}

---

Thanks to the answers, I was able to solve the issue by adding the insurance field to Provider Model, as it looks like this now:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name','first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password','is_available','is_activated','insurance'
    ];
```

Comment: have u added `insurance` field to your model?

Comment: no, I never touched any model in this project, and it works usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `create()` method, you need to add the field to `$fillable` array:

```
protected $fillable = ['insurance', ....];
```

You need to do that since `create()` is using `fill()` method to fill model fields for you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: No, he doesn't. Only if he is using a fillable array. Which is optional.

Comment: @Amarnasan it's not optional when you're using `create()` method. It will simply not work without `fillable` or `guarded` arrays filled.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a "fillable" array in your model, you must add the "insurance" field to it.

Comment: In a comment above you told that `fillable` is optional, but it's not. So, not "if you set...", but you always need to use `fillable` or `guarded` to make `create()` work since it uses the `fill()` method internally. So, if you'll not define it, `create()` will skip all the fields which aren't in `fillable`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes, you already commented that. Why repeat that comment here? Are you gonna chase all of my answers in the site and make the same comment? :-D

Answer (score 1):

As you have altered table using migration you just need to update `InsuranceProvider` model in app directory and add `insurance` field to the fillable array in order to make this working.